# Insert value with jquery to tags input element

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input, jquery-tags-input

I want to insert value through jquery to tags input element html. But didn't work.

My code JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
  $('#tags-input').tagsInput();
  var tagsValue = 'Jakarta,Bogor,Bandung';
  $('#tags-input').val(tagsValue);
});
```

My code html :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="tags-input" />
```

But the result is empty
[image: wrong result]

And i want the result is
[image: true result]

how can i do it? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Did you include plugin file in page? Any errors thrown in dev tools console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `add` method of tagsinput.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
  var tagInputEle = $('#tags-input');
  tagInputEle.tagsinput();
  tagInputEle.tagsinput('add', 'Jakarta');
  tagInputEle.tagsinput('add', 'Bogor');
  tagInputEle.tagsinput('add', 'Bandung');
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
   background: red;
   padding: 4px;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-MoRNloxbStBcD8z3M/2BmnT+rg4IsMxPkXaGh2zD6LGNNFE80W3onsAhRcMAMrSoyWL9xD7Ert0men7vR8LUZg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" integrity="sha512-xmGTNt20S0t62wHLmQec2DauG9T+owP9e6VU8GigI0anN7OXLip9i7IwEhelasml2osdxX71XcYm6BQunTQeQg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" integrity="sha512-9UR1ynHntZdqHnwXKTaOm1s6V9fExqejKvg5XMawEMToW4sSw+3jtLrYfZPijvnwnnE8Uol1O9BcAskoxgec+g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="tags-input" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the order of setting value before initializing the plugin and it works fine.

If you intitalize plugin forst you need to us the plugin methods to insert  tag values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tagsValue = 'Jakarta,Bogor,Bandung';
  $('#tags-input').val(tagsValue).tagsinput();
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-MoRNloxbStBcD8z3M/2BmnT+rg4IsMxPkXaGh2zD6LGNNFE80W3onsAhRcMAMrSoyWL9xD7Ert0men7vR8LUZg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" integrity="sha512-xmGTNt20S0t62wHLmQec2DauG9T+owP9e6VU8GigI0anN7OXLip9i7IwEhelasml2osdxX71XcYm6BQunTQeQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" integrity="sha512-9UR1ynHntZdqHnwXKTaOm1s6V9fExqejKvg5XMawEMToW4sSw+3jtLrYfZPijvnwnnE8Uol1O9BcAskoxgec+g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="tags-input" />
```